# Are questions about fan works allowed?

Tags: discussion

Assuming an anime or manga fan work is reasonably well known, are questions about it allowed?

For example:

- [Sailor Nothing](http://stefangagne.com/sailornothing/)
- [Yu-Gi-Oh! Abridged](http://yugiohabridged.com/)

Comment: What kind of questions?

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason, why questions about fan-made media shouldn't be allowed. If it fits the rules of Anime.SE, the question can be about any work, and I doubt that it needs to be well-known. You should, however, try to ask the author in case it's just something small like a short fan fiction.